# Probleme in installing and compiling the MEX interfaces

Tags: c, c++11, mex

It is my first attempt at using `mex` files. I'm  following and trying to reproduce the steps indicated [here](https://www-m3.ma.tum.de/Software/ODEInstall) in order to use the ODE solvers.

I have setup the programming language to C++.

```
  >> mex -setup
MEX configured to use 'MinGW64 Compiler (C)' for C language compilation.
Warning: The MATLAB C and Fortran API has changed to support MATLAB
     variables with more than 2^32-1 elements. You will be required
     to update your code to utilize the new API.
     You can find more information about this at:
     https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/upgrading-mex-files-to-use-64-bit-api.html.

To choose a different language, select one from the following:
 mex -setup C++ 
 mex -setup FORTRAN
Error using mex
No supported compiler was found. For options, visit https://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers.

MEX configured to use 'MinGW64 Compiler (C++)' for C++ language compilation.
Warning: The MATLAB C and Fortran API has changed to support MATLAB
     variables with more than 2^32-1 elements. You will be required
     to update your code to utilize the new API.
     You can find more information about this at:
     https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/upgrading-mex-files-to-use-64-bit-api.html.
```

But when I run `mex -v` to check if everything is prepared and set for compilation.
I get the following error message:

```
 >> mex -v
Verbose mode is on.
Error using mex
Not enough input arguments.
```

When I call  `compile` as per the procedure in the aforementioned link, I get the error seen in the next screenshot :

```
>> compile
Verbose mode is on.
... Looking for compiler 'MinGW64 Compiler (C)' ...
... Looking for environment variable 'MW_MINGW64_LOC' ...Yes ('C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2018a\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset').
... Looking for file 'C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2018a\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset\bin\gcc.exe' ...Yes.
... Looking for folder 'C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2018a\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset' ...Yes.
Found installed compiler 'MinGW64 Compiler (C)'.
Set PATH = C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2018a\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset\bin;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\extern\include\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\extern\include;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\simulink\include;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\lib\win64;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\bin;C:\Users\rayane benyoucef\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\
Set INCLUDE = C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2018a\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset\include;;C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2018a\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset\include;;
Set LIB = C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2018a\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset\lib;;C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2018a\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset\lib;;
Set MW_TARGET_ARCH = win64;win64;
Set LIBPATH = C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\extern\lib\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\extern\lib\win64;
Error using mex
MEX cannot find library 'gfortran' specified with the -l option.
 MEX looks for a file with one of the names:
 libgfortran.lib
 gfortran.lib
 Please specify the path to this library with the -L option.


Error in compile (line 75)
 mex('-c',args{:},'dop853Mex.c','dopri5Mex.c','options.c','tif.c');
```

Can anyone, give me a hand to find out what's the problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please post text, not pictures of text. See [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/1362568)

Comment: Ok I will do it thanks, I think the error accures because there is no fortran compiler installed, is there any free fortran compiler because I don't seem to find any. Thanks

Comment: `mex -v` is not for checking if everything is ready.... And, do you have libgfortran and gfortran? That webpage seems to be outdated